# In LEGO mindstorms NXT programming: is it possible to download a file from a robot onto the computer?

Tags: nxt, mindstorms

I've lost the file for a project, but the robot still has it, and I'm wondering if it is possible to transfer the file onto my computer from the robot, and continue to work on it. How would you do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can download it back in computer. But you can't work on it anymore - it is already compiled (has `.rxe` extension). However you can download it on another NXT and continue to use there. You can edit and work only with `.rbt` files.

---

My LEGO MINDSTORMS NXT program doesn't work anymore for already two months... Some problems with flash player. So I can't provide any screenshots.